# Ajuda com menu em css

Tags: html, css

Galera montei um menu bem simples em css. Porém estou com um problema. Esse menu fica dentro de uma div `header` que fica fixa na tela. Por tanto se o menu tiver muita opção não e possível selecionar elas pois ele fica cortado.
Uma solução simples e legal seria eu colocar uma scroll, porém preciso que o menu abra do tamanho da tela, e se ele não couber tem que aparecer uma scroll. Tentei fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
        .top_sub_menu .scroll {
        overflow: auto;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Porem não deu certo, alguém sabe alguma forma de resolver isso

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
}
.sub_menu_fim {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.sub_menu_inicio {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.top_sub_menu {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.top_sub_menu .scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.title_menu {
  background: #0091FF;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  height: 25px;
}
.menu:hover div {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}
.link_menu {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.link_menu_esquerda {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.link_menu_direita {
  margin: 0px 0 0 -229px;
}
.sub_menu {
  padding: 10px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #484848;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.sub_menu:hover {
  background: #0091FF;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <div class='menu'>
    <div class='mini_botao mini_botao_blue_hover'>
      menu
    </div>

    <div class='link_menu link_menu_esquerda'>
      <div class='top_sub_menu'>
        <div class='sub_menu_inicio'></div>
        <div class='title_menu'>Caixas</div>
        <div class="scroll">
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
          <div class='sub_menu'>menu 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class='sub_menu_fim'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua o `heigth: 100%` por `height: 100vh;`

```
.top_sub_menu .scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Veja no [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVB3t/1757/)

`vh` vai configurar a altura para `100%`. É uma nova unidade CSS3. Todos os principais navegadores modernos o suportam.

Veja a compatibilidade [aqui](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: muito bom isso ai viu ;) obrigado